# RegEx match strings with more than 5 Slashs

Tags: regex, filemaker

I need to find URLs with more then 5 slashs and ignore trailing slash.

Like match

```
https://www.url.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/
```

Not matching

```
https://www.url.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you show your closest attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
^(?:[^/\r\n]*/){6,}[^/\r\n]+
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of line
  (?:           : start non capture group
    [^/\r\n]*   : 0 or more any character that is not a slash or a linebreak
    /           : 1 slash
  ){6,}         : end group, must appear 6 or more times
  [^/\r\n]+     : 1 or more any character that is not a slash or a linebreak
```

Comment: Works, thnk you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your source text contains only a single URL and
nothing more, you can use:

```
^((?:[^\/]*\/){6,}[^\/]+)\/?$
```

Description:

- `^` - Start of the string.
- `(` - Start of the capturing group, containing:

  - `(?:` - Start of the non-capturing group, needed due to
    a quantifier after it.
  - `[^\/]*\/` - A sequence of chars other than `/` (maybe empty)
    and `/`.
  - `){6,}` - End of the non-capturing group, must occur 6 or
    more times.
  - `[^\/]+` - A sequence of chars other than `/`, this time non-empty.
- `)` - End of the capturing group.
- `\/?` - The trailing slash (if any).
- `$` - End of the string.

The whole match contains the whole URL and the capturing group contains
what you are actually interested in - the URL **without** the trailing
slash (if any).

Comment: OP doesn't want to match if there is a trailing slash. Your regex matches all text between 2 URLs on separate lines.

Comment: I do not agree. See the "Like match". It does contain the trailing slash. The only requirement is that this trailing slash should not be the part of match, and in my solution group 1 does not contain it. The URL should not match if it contains 5 or less slashes, **excluding** the trailing slash.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I misread ;(, but my 2nd remark is still valid.